# How to restructure layouts in NextJS 13 using the new app router so I can still use the metadata api?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navigation, next.js13

I am using the newer app router for NextJS 13 and I'm having trouble understanding how to structure the app so I can use the metadata api. My main page is in the root of the app folder.
[image: app folder structure]

The app is really simple. I have the main page and two additional routes. I need my navbar to appear on the homepage and both routes. To do this I added the nav to the root layout file where I also added a portal for a modal I need. The problem I am having is caused because I need useState to control open and closing the modal which means I have to designate the file as a client component with 'use client' and that means that now I cannot use the metadata api because it will only work in server components.

```
    'use client'

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MainNav from '@/components/navigation/main-nav/Navbar';
import MobileModal from '@/components/ui/modal/MobileModal';
import './globals.css';
// import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });

export const metadata = {
  title: 'App title',
  description:
    'Site description here',
};

import StyledComponentsRegistry from 'lib/registry';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  const [displayModal, setDisplayModal] = useState(false);

  const showModalHandler = () => {
    setDisplayModal(true);
  };

  const hideModalHandler = () => {
    setDisplayModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <html>
      <body>
        <MainNav onShowmodal={showModalHandler} onClose={hideModalHandler} />
        {displayModal && <MobileModal onClose={hideModalHandler} />}
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
        <div id="backdrop-root"></div>
        <div id="overlay-root"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Is there a better way to structure this where I could keep the root layout as a server component and still have use of my portals and navigation? The only reason I was using next for this project was to improve the SEO. I know I could go back to the pages router set up but I was hoping to find a solution that can use the app router.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - well it looks like the solution was pretty simple but I'm not sure if this was the greatest way to do it. I created another layout file in the root of the app folder where the navbar state can be managed.

[image: folders]

New Layout file - mainLayout.js:

```
'use client';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import MainNav from '@/components/navigation/main-nav/Navbar';
import MobileModal from '@/components/ui/modal/MobileModal';

const MainLayout = () => {
  const [displayModal, setDisplayModal] = useState(false);

  const showModalHandler = () => {
    setDisplayModal(true);
  };

  const hideModalHandler = () => {
    setDisplayModal(false);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <MainNav onShowmodal={showModalHandler} onClose={hideModalHandler} />
      {displayModal && <MobileModal onClose={hideModalHandler} />}
    </>
  );
};
export default MainLayout;
```

Modified root layout file

```
import MainLayout from './mainLayout';
    import './globals.css';
    // import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
    
   

     // const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });
        
        export const metadata = {
          title: 'App title',
          description:
            'Site description',
        };
        
        import StyledComponentsRegistry from 'lib/registry';
        
        export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
          return (
            <html>
              <body>
                <MainLayout />
                <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
                <div id="backdrop-root"></div>
                <div id="overlay-root"></div>
              </body>
            </html>
          );
        }
```

You can just plug in the new layout into the root layout and now the metadata is showing up like it should and the nav and portals work fine. Perhaps there is a better way but this works. Main take away is making sure to separate everything (client and server) and have no state or event listeners in any layout file that you want to use the metadata api. Not sure if this feels like an improvement over the older way using , it seems there are just extra steps to do the same thing.